# How does liquidity affect currency price while trading

Tags: trading, foreign-exchange, liquidity

I would like to know what happens to the market when the following situation arises on the GBP/USD currency pair:

-Say some big investor sells 100 million pounds but current liquidity in the market is only about 50 million for argument sake, which way will the market move to fill the big investors order?

Please explain why?
Thank you

Comment: you mean attempt to sell? :P  Also, is the trade priced above or below the spot price?  There are several other variables as well: fill-or-kill, limit order, market order?

Comment: @Ross thanks, yes say if a large bank sell 100 million pounds. Well i am not sure what you mean by above or below spot price? Sorry i am new to this. yes its a market order.

Comment: Not exactly sure on FX markets so I won't put an answer below but most large market orders to sell will lower the price of securities.  Think of it this way:  Someone has to buy the remaining order(s). When you buy something you want the best/cheapest price you can pay ;)  This is way oversimplified quasi-answer btw.

Comment: So there are more pounds to sell and less dollars to buy. So pounds would become cheaper and dollars expensive. So if previous for every pound you go 2 dollars, you may now only get 1.5 dollars for a pound. Of Course it woud cascade the futures and quite a few other things.

Comment: @Dheer, Why was this question closed on the basis of being on economics? It has nothing to do with economics, it is about trading currencies and liquidity of the markets.

Comment: This is economics of Demand and Supply applied to Fx. The question does not show any relevance to personal finance, i.e. use of 100 Million. Further the entire question is framed with some hypothetical situation.

Comment: @Dheer, it has nothing to do with economics, it has to do with liquidity of the FX markets. If we took your point of view half the questions on investing and trading should then be closed as well.

Answer (score 2):

Liquidity works very similarly in currencies to how it works for equities.  A large sudden order will move the price of the product and correspondingly its derivatives.  In this case the value of the pound will drop against the dollar and all the related forwards/futures and options.

The main confusion with currencies however is how they are quoted. The pound is generally quoted as some number of dollars per pound.  In this case for the value of the pound to drop the "price" in dollars per pound would drop as well as a pound will get you fewer dollars.  Some currencies pairs are generally quoted the other direction though.

There is however tons of liquidity in major currencies and the market should be able to absorb $100MM pounds during London hours without too much issue.  $500MM starts to be troublesome.